# login form should redirect to register page for in 1st login next time it should redirected to home page

Tags: plugins, javascript, jquery, redirect, forms

I'm new to WP I need your help in redirect the user only for 1st time logging,
in my landing page, 1 created a login form if the user logged for 1st time means it should redirect to register page and 2nd-time onwards it should redirect to cust URL
will you please guide me on how to do this

Comment: the answer it's a quite an articulate answer, not so quick..
but you should rely on some values that you must save the first time. The easiest is to use the user_meta table and its relative functions `get_user_meta()` ( to check if a value exists) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/ and `update_user_meta()` to save the control meta on the first login

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.